# Silverlight performance differs while using administrator account and limited user account

Tags: silverlight, administration

We have a Silverlight application that runs in intranet environment. It has more than 3000 unique user per day (application for company's retail chain).

Some days ago we noticed that it takes about 5 minutes for application to load (and freezing browser for that time) on some of our user's computers. Our technical support done a testing and figured that the issue is in Silverlight.

If you start any Silverlight application using this computer the IE falls in "Not Responding" state for several minutes and than operates normaly. If user using an administrative account Silverlight applications starts instantly without any lag.

What can be the source of this issue? And what testing can be done?

Application runs on standart hardware and software for every user (Windows 7 Pro, IE9, Silverlight 4, i3, 4Gb of Ram)

Comment: There are various tools to profile Silverlight apps (including Visual Studio if you have the profiler: http://www.nachmore.com/2010/profiling-silverlight-4-with-visual-studio-2010/). I would start by this, beyond a careful review of the app code itself.

Comment: The issue occurs on loading ANY Silverlight application on that computer. So it is not about application itself, as about possible mistakes in user configuration or computer configuration.

Comment: Ok for the review then, but a profiler still could help.

Comment: Profiled this application using [Jetbrains Profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler) - application takes about 300ms to load. Will try to get access to these computers with issue and profile them remotely.

Comment: So i got an access to one of these computers. When I'm running SL application using admin account it works and loads really fast. When SL app running under non-admin user the issue shows itself (the browser freeze for several minutes and then runs normally). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ran the profiler on these slow SL apps?

Comment: I was able to profile application only using admin-user account. Using standart user account I couldn't even run the profiling tool because it crashed with some critical exception. I think it's an user permissions issue. Maybe some of the .NET components are locked. Do you know any tool that I can use to check it?

Comment: Not on top of my head. Maybe you could try procmon (file & network) to check unusual disk activity. Also fiddler2 on the network.